# pdflatex endless loop and page headings wrong aligned with dateiliste/babel

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, pdftex, babel

In the following code the heading is wrong aligned if babel and dateiliste are loaded together. Furthermore the whole MWE goes into an endless loop if the first line is removed.

```
% remove to let pdflatex go into endless loop
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag} 

\documentclass[english]{scrbook}
%

\usepackage{babel}     % <- remove to correct heading alignment
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{dateiliste} % <- remove to correct heading alignment

% only for demonstration
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{wrong aligned heading}
\blindtext[1]
\section{section}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

The system is Texlive 2012, all packages updated on windows 7.

The endless loop comes from dateiliste, `\tracingall` shows at the end these lines

```
\dateiliste@mainfile ->LaTeXTemplate.tex
\@filelist ->\@filelist 
\@filelist ->\@filelist 
...
```

which never stops

Comment: Seems like a bug in `dateilist`

Comment: I wrote the author already, but so far he did not answer any mail from me...

Comment: Sorry, I tried to have a look to the code, but being the doc in German I can't understand what the code is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: I think that `\dateiliste@mainfile` adds the main file (i.e. the file you are compiling) to the list of files.  Somehow, something is putting that into a loop.  Try `\usepackage[noaddmain]{dateiliste}`

Comment: Indeed that solved the endless loop, but the wrong aligned headings still remains. Which was the reason I created the MWE in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The incorrect placement of the running head is a bug in `dateiliste.sty`.   Loading the `babel` package causes `dateiliste` to run the command `\dateiliste@babel` which in turn runs `\addto` on `\extra`language for a short list of languages including English.  Unfortunately, a number of line endings in that code are not commented out, resulting in some extra spaces, and these work their way in to the page marks.  This is apparent even with standard `book`, but below is a minimal example in your set-up.  Note that `\listfiles` is added to the preamble to prevent `dateiliste` going into its infinite loop.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{dateiliste}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Heading}

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample wrong output]

To correct this, copy `dateiliste.sty` to a new file and correct the definition of `\dateiliste@babel` so that lines end with `%` percent signs after closing brackets `}`.  Below is the English part of that definition.

```
\newcommand*{\dateiliste@babel}{
   \addto{\extrasenglish}{%
      \renewcommand*\fileListPreamble{%
         Here is the list of all files used during the run of \LaTeX{}
         which produced this document.\footnote{More precisely, it is
            the list of files used one \LaTeX-run before the one which
            produced this document, but after some runs the list
            should stabilize.}
      }%
      \renewcommand*\fileListName{List of Files}%
      \renewcommand*\fileNameName{file name}%
      \renewcommand*\pageName{page}%
      \renewcommand*\dateName{release date}%
       \renewcommand*\verName{ver.}%
       \renewcommand*\descriptionName{description}%
   }%
```

Using the new style file gives the following output with the heading correctly flush left.

[image: Correct output]

Alternatively, you can move the `babel` package *after* the `dateiliste` package, delete the offending hook and, if you need them, make the specific definitions:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{dateiliste}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\dateiliste@babel\relax  % Clear the hook
\makeatother

%% Make the English definitions
\renewcommand*\fileListPreamble{%
Here is the list of all files used during the run of \LaTeX{}
which produced this document.\footnote{More precisely, it is
the list of files used one \LaTeX-run before the one which
produced this document, but after some runs the list
should stabilize.}
}%
\renewcommand*\fileListName{List of Files}%
\renewcommand*\fileNameName{file name}%
\renewcommand*\pageName{page}%
\renewcommand*\dateName{release date}%
\renewcommand*\verName{ver.}%
\renewcommand*\descriptionName{description}%
%% End of English definitions

\usepackage{blindtext}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Heading}

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your analysis (and also to Markus Kohm, who notified me per mail of this question, and proposed a similar solution). I'll try to correct this and release a new version soon.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Matthias for reporting, and thanks to Andrew Swann and Markus Kohm (by mail to me) for analyzing the problems.

The **header indenting** problem was caused by Babel executing `\extrasenglish` at this location, and in this macro I did insert misplaced spaces (several of them) by not commenting out the line endings, as should always be done when doing "programming" (not typesetting) after the preamble. Looks like I didn't realize that this is actually executed inside the document, and I didn't really test my translation feature with headings switched on.

I commented out all the line endings in the respective parts of the package.

The **endless loop** comes from trying to manipulate `\@filelist` when it is actually undefined. This part of the program tried to remove `\jobname.tex,` from the file list before adding it again:

```
  \@expandtwoargs\@removeelement{\dateiliste@mainfile}%
  \@filelist\@filelist
```

This occurs when you use this package (and don't give the `[noaddmain]` option) but forgot to include the `\listfiles` command in the preamble. Looks like I never considered this case, as the main goal of my package is to create a file list.

My solution now gives a warning in this case (and leaves out the whole manipulation of `\@filelist`).

I just uploaded version 0.6 to CTAN which should fix both problems.